# How can I create a static variable in a Swift ViewController?

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, static

I'm having a lot of difficulty moving from Objective-C to Swift and writing my first Swift app. I'm having more difficulty finding anything online in a concise manner.

How can I create a static var in a ViewController class.

For example

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    static var SOME_VIEW_WIDTH_AND_HEIGHT = 70.0

    ...

    func someFunc() {
        self.someView = SomeView.init(frame: CGRectMake(0,0,SOME_VIEW_WIDTH_AND_HEIGHT,SOME_VIEW_WIDTH_AND_HEIGHT)
```

etc.

However, I cannot do this. How can this be achieved?

Comment: `ViewController.SOME_VIEW_WIDTH_AND_HEIGHT` does work - if you fix the `CGFloat` vs. `Double` incomparability.

Comment: @luk2302 Is this the correct syntax `static var SIMPL_CIRCLE_VIEW_WIDTH : CGFloat = 70.0`? *shutter*

Comment: yes, that is one valid way!

Comment: @luk2302 what would be the most accepted way? The syntax strikes me as odd.

Comment: You could alternatively define it as `static var SIMPL_CIRCLE_VIEW_WIDTH  = CGFloat(70)`.